# Single-Column Matrix Indexing

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I've got a .tcl file with data representing a large three-dimensional matrix, and all values associated with the matrix appended in a single column, like this:

```
128 128 512
3.2867
4.0731
5.2104
4.114
2.6472
1.0059
0.68474
...
```

If I load the file into the command window and `whos` the variable, I have this:

```
 whos K
  Name            Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  K         8388810x3             201331440  double
```

The two additional columns seem to be filled with `NaN`s, which don't appear in the original file.  Is this a standard way for MATLAB to store a three-dimensional matrix?  I'm more familiar with the .mat way of storing a matrix, and I'm curious if there's a quick command I can run to revert it to a more friendly format.

Comment: If all values are stored in a single column, why does the first line have three values?

Comment: And why are there so many extra rows? (8388810 vs. 8388608)

Comment: Those are both good questions.  The first line has three values because the file was originally formatted as an input for a Fortran script; I'm just reappropriating things.  It was essentially output as a header, with the data appended.  If I ignore that line, though, that still leaves 201 extra rows, as noted.  I'm working on tracking down the original source to get that resolved.  That anomaly aside, though, the reshape solution works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file's first line (`128 128 512`) gives it 3 columns.  I don't know why there are <s>2</s>so many extra rows (128*128*512 = 8388608), but your 3d matrix can probably be constructed like this:

```
N = 128*128*512;
mat = reshape(tab(2:N+1,1),[128 128 512]);
```

What's on the last hundred lines of the table that gets loaded?